# Quick couple of CSS inheritance questions

Tags: css, inheritance, shorthand

On the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html) website the border-style property (as an example) is marked as inherited 'No', yet one of the allowed values is 'inherit'. Why is this?

Does inherited 'No' mean in this case that the default value is not to inherit?
If so, then I can see that anyway by looking at the default value which is 'none'.

Secondly, am I right in thinking that the 'inherit' value cannot be used for individual properties in a short-hand statement?

Comment: "Secondly, am I right in thinking that the 'inherit' value cannot be used for individual properties in a short-hand statement?" such as "border 2px inherit"?

Comment: Yes, and thinking about it can't be possible because the parser would not know which property the inherit value applied to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means if you have a DIV with a border and another DIV inside, the inside one will not take on the border properties of the parent **automatically**. You can force inheritance using "inherit" on the child element.

This differs from things like font-size definitions that do get inherited automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The notation “Inherit: No” means that “normal” inheritance does not apply. In “normal” inheritance, if no style sheet assigns a value for a property for an element, the value of the property for the element’s parent is used. I use “normal” in quotes, since this applies to some properties only, as indicated by the “Inherit: No” notations.

The special value `inherit` is something quite different. When it is used, the entire value part of the declaration must consist of the word `inherit` only, and it simply declares that the property value is to be the same as for the element’s parent (no matter what the property is). Contrary to what the [CSS 2.1 spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#value-def-inherit), this does not force or “enforce” inheritance; the declaration participates in the cascade and it may lose to other rules (as you may guess from the example that uses the `!important` specifier).